# Require some understanding for Singleton Pattern

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I am going to paste a code here and had a question regarding that which I wanted to understand merely, based on the logical way.

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject {
NSString *enteredCode; 
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *enteredCode;

@end


@synthesize enteredCode;

-(void) addInput:(NSString *) input
{ 
self.enteredCode = [self.enteredCode stringByAppendingString:input];
}

- (void)dealloc {
[enteredCode release];
}

@end
```

In my code, if I utilize "**self.enteredCode = [self.enteredCode stringByAppendingString:input**];"

everything works fine but "**enteredCode = [self.enteredCode stringByAppendingString:input];**" it gets exc_bad_access, and I am just wondering why this case be?

I am just trying to understand what difference really does it makes without having self there?

Thanks.

Comment: Minor point, not related to your question:  `NSString` properties should be declared as `copy` not `retain`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not to do with singletons. When you do `self.enteredCode` you are going through the property which is set to 'retain'. The `stringByAppendingString` method is a convenience method with returns an autoreleased object to you, meaning that it will be released at some point on the next run loop. You need to retain this value to stop it being released, which is fine when you assign it **through** the property as it is properly retained by you and you can use it as you like.

When you reference the variable directory (without the `self.`) you bypass this and as such you don't ever retain the value, the value is subsequently released and you reference bad memory and BOOOOOOOOM, bad access.

Comment: Further clarification: always remember that `self.foo = bar` is the same as `[self setFoo:bar]`.

Answer (score 1):

when you call `self.enteredCode = XXX` it will call `[self setEnteredCode:XXX]`. Since you are using a retain property this will release the old value of enteredCode, and retain the new value.

if you directly manipulate the enteredCode variable you will have memleaks and crashes because it will try to release something that is not retained later.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, self.enteredCode works but enteredCode fails.

If that's the case then I believe it's because you're bypassing the property and setting the iVar directly.  That means you're assigned an auto released object and bypassing the retain mechanism.

Consider using something like _enteredCode for your iVars do it's clearer in your code when you're bypassing properties.

Comment: bryanmac, in my case actually I don't want to bypass the property and rather retain the newest information, for which self.enteredCode will make sense. Thanks.